# Python 2.7 - Error at line 298 - What is wrong with my code?

Tags: python

Here is the code from the last if: to the next if:

```
if msgtype == "\x00":
    utflength=struct.unpack("!h", data[:2])[0]
    name=str(data[2:int(utflength)+2])
    data=data[utflength+2:]
    utflength=struct.unpack("!h", data[:2])[0]
    message=data[2:utflength+2]
    self.sendOutput("To " + name + ": " + message)
else:
    utflength=struct.unpack("!h", data[:2])[0]
    name=str(data[2:int(utflength)+2])
    data=data[utflength+2:]
    utflength=struct.unpack("!h", data[:2])[0]
    message=data[2:utflength+2]
    self.sendOutput("From " + name + ": " + message)
else:
    utflength=struct.unpack("!h", data[:2])[0]
    name=str(data[2:int(utflength)+2])
    data=data[utflength+2:]
    utflength=struct.unpack("!h", data[:2])[0]
    message=data[2:utflength+2]
    self.sendOutput("From " + name + ": " + message)
```

Comment: That's unreadable.  Please format it correctly.  Please **Edit** the question and properly format the code according to the instructions on the right side of the edit page.

Comment: Also, *what is the error message* and *what's line 298* would also be helpful.

Comment: @100thninja, I have improved the formatting of your question but you still need to provide more information if you wish to get an answer, as @kindall said we need to know the error message and which line it is occurring on, please bear in mind that we don't have your whole file so telling us line #298 is not helpful, you should add a comment to the end of that line of code.

Answer (score 11):

There can only be one `else` per `if` statement.

You can, however, distinguish different cases with `elif`:

```
if condition1:
   ...
elif condition2:
   assert not condition1
   ...
else:
   assert not condition1  and  not condition2
   ...
```

For details on `if`, `else`, `elif`, and other flow control statements, refer to the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html).